# Image not opening link when clicked

Tags: html

I'm trying to make an image open a link when you click on it, and it's not working.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head> IPL STATISTICS </head>`enter code here`
<br>
<br>
<h1> <strong> MOST NUMBER OF RUNS </strong></h1>
 <img src="/images/ORGANE CUP.jpg " width=" 400" height="300" 
<a href=" https://www.hindustantimes.com/cricket/ipl/orange-cap-winner"
> </a>
<br>
   <br>
   <h2> <strong> MOST NUMBER OF WICKETS </strong> </h2>
  <img src="/images/ipl-purple-cap.webp"width= "400"  height="300"
   <a href ="https://sports.ndtv.com/ipl-2022/stats/4623-13-bowling-statsdetail"> </a>
<br>
   <br>
 <h3> <strong> MOST TROPHES </strong> </h3>
    <img src ="images/IPL-Trophy-1.webp" width="400" height="300"
     a href = "https://www.careerpower.in/ipl-winners-list.html" > </a>
```

Comment: The `<img ...>`  needs to go in between `<a ...>` and `</a>`. It looks like you should take a [basic html tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Getting_started_with_the_web/HTML_basics).

Answer (score 4):

You are putting tags in the wrong way, try to take recommended tag, and you won't get the issues. you can use it this way.

```
<a href=" https://www.hindustantimes.com/cricket/ipl/orange-cap-winner">
<img src="/images/orange cup.jpg " width=" 400" height="300" >
</a>
```